# For loop with function

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a function that looks something like this

```
const calculate = (number) => {
  if (number === undefined) {
    number = 1;
  }
  result = 5 + number;
  return result;
}

restricted = [6, 7, 8]
if (restricted.includes(calculate()) {
... //i need something here i guess
}
```

If `restricted.includes(calculate())` I want to repeat this function, add 1 to `number` until I get `false`.

For example, `calculate()` will return 6, the if condition will be `true` and I want to add `1` to the `number` and to run `calculate(2)` which will return 7 - again the if condition will be true so I need to run `calculate(3)`. Oh no, it's still true. Now we run `calculate(4)` and finally return 9.

How do I write the second part?

Comment: My guess is that you want to write recursive functions. If that is the case, try searching for recursion. Recursive functions must have a [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#base_case). For starters, try looking up "fibonacci function recursion JavaScript" on google.

Comment: @J.Lee i am trying to do something with dates. So if the result is Wednesday for example, I want to run the function again and add 1 to the number so that I can get Thursday. But sometimes I have two restricted days in a row so I need to run the function twice.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the clarification. You might want to add that into your description so that people trying to help have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve. Just out of curiosity, if you are working with dates, why not work with the [date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) API? Sorry, just slightly confused as to what you are trying to achieve based on current description. It might just be me though.

Comment: I am using it, but I parse the result to get it into a certain format

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [6,7,8];

const calculate = (number) => {
  if (number === undefined) {
    number = 1;
  }
  result = 5 + number;
  return result;
}

[...array, undefined].forEach(x=>console.log(calculate(x)))
```

`array` was given by you, just append an additional `undefined` into the array and using `forEach()` to loop and perform function call

Comment: When I call calculate() I still get 6 as a result. I need to get 9. I want it to do calculate(1), calculate(2), calculate(3), calculate(4) and then to stop.

Comment: I really dont understand what you're doing now. what's the result of `calculate(1)`? and `calculate(2)`? and `calculate(3)` and `calculate(4)`

Comment: The real result of `calculate(1)` is 6, but six is a restricted number, so I want to add 1 to `number` which will do `calculate(2)` and the result is 7, which is again a restricted number, and so on until I get 9 as a result.

Comment: What is `restricted` number

Comment: Please include all these conditions/descriptions into your questions